# Alfanumerico determinato por un new Date()

Tags: java

Quiero hacer un generador de ID "aleatorio" que sea un **Alfanumérico de 24 carácteres.**
Para "evitar" **colisiones**, quiero que el ID esté formado por:

- Los primeros X cáracteres vegan determinados por la fecha.
- Los restantes un simple random alphanumerical (esta parte no tiene misterio).

Cuál es la mejor aproximación para la primera parte?
Entiendo que el objetivo inicial es tener un long/int en plan `new Date().getTime() % <caparlo a un determinado rango>` , pero luego este long/int no tengo claro cuál es la manera óptima para pasarlo a una cadena alfanumérica.

Gracias!

PD: Si hay una alternativa conocida ya existente para generar dichos ID (alfanuméricos de 24 óptimos para evitar colisiones), también lo valoro!

Comment: ¿Por qué no usas la marca del tiempo sin más?

Answer (score 0):

Espero te sirva,puedes agregar o disminuir los caracteres del id generado

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class gokuPass {
public static String generadorDePasword() {
        String fecha=String.valueOf(LocalDate.now()).replaceAll("-", "");
        int diferecial=24-fecha.length();//diferencia de los 24 caracteres con la cantidad de digitos de la fecha 
        String alfaMin = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        String alfaMay = alfaMin.toUpperCase();
        String numeros = "0123456789";

        String datosToString = alfaMin + alfaMay + numeros;
        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    
        if (diferecial < 1) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < diferencial; i++) {
            // 0-62 (exclusivo), retorno aleatorio 0-61
            int rndCharAt = random.nextInt(datosToString.length());
            char rndChar = datosToString.charAt(rndCharAt);

            sb.append(rndChar);
        }

        return fecha+sb.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) { 

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println("Id de 24 carcateres Aleatorio: " + generadorDePasword());
            System.out.println("\n");
        }

    }
}
```